# How to restore the master database?

Tags: sql-server

Hi I want to restore master database .

For that I tried to start my instance in single user mode.

But I got an error :

> ```
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Binn>sqlservr.exe - m -s TST_01
> 2009-03-18 13:17:35.18 Server      Authentication mode is WINDOWS-ONLY.
> 2009-03-18 13:17:35.18 Server      Error: 17112, Severity: 16, State: 1.
> 2009-03-18 13:17:35.18 Server      An invalid startup option  was supplied, either from the registry or the command prompt. Correct or remove the option.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's just a typo in your message, but in the command you wrote there's a blank between the first hyphen and the letter "m". You wrote **- m** instead of **-m**.